# How can I reload gunicorn server using ansible?

Tags: django, ansible, gunicorn

I have a gunicorn server which run my Django website on localhost:8000. Currently I use lsof to check for pid and shutdown it using `kill -9` command. Then I start gunicorn server again.

```
    - name: Find all process using port 8000
      ansible.builtin.shell: "lsof -t -i:8000"
      register: processes_on_port

    - name: Stop all processes running on port 8000
      ansible.builtin.shell: "kill -9 {{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ processes_on_port.stdout_lines }}"
      ignore_errors: yes

    - name: Start gunicorn server
      community.general.gunicorn:
        app: "django_my_website.wsgi"
        chdir: /opt/my_website/django_my_website
        venv: /opt/my_website_venv
```

I want to reload it without shutting down using Ansible playbook. Is there any way I can do it ?

Comment: Install it correctly as a systemd service then use the systemd module to manage it. See https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html#systemd

Comment: Thank you sir, you solve my problem. Can you make it your comment an answer and  i would accept it@Zeitounator